# Assembler macros are not expanded when using inline assembly targeting Arduino

Tags: assembly, arduino, macros

I'm trying to compile a library called TVout. When I try it, Arduino Linker throws these messages:

```
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:135: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:190: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:192: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:195: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:198: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:201: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:204: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:207: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:212: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:215: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:264: Error: unknown opcode `svprt'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:268: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:272: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:273: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:275: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:276: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:278: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:279: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:281: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:282: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:284: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:285: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:287: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:288: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:291: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:293: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:295: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:296: Error: unknown opcode `svprt'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:298: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:346: Error: unknown opcode `svprt'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:350: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:353: Error: unknown opcode `delay1'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:355: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:356: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:358: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:359: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:361: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:362: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:364: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:365: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:367: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:368: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:370: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:371: Error: unknown opcode `delay3'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:373: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:376: Error: unknown opcode `delay2'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:378: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:379: Error: unknown opcode `svprt'
/tmp/ccxegFH3.s:381: Error: unknown opcode `o1bs'
```

Errors come from video_gen.cpp. Piece of code:

```
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "ADD    r26,r28\n\t"
    "ADC    r27,r29\n\t"
    //save PORTB
    "svprt  %[port]\n\t"

    "rjmp   enter6\n"
"loop6:\n\t"
    "bst    __tmp_reg__,0\n\t"          //8
    "o1bs   %[port]\n"
"enter6:\n\t"
    "LD     __tmp_reg__,X+\n\t"         //1
    "delay1\n\t"
    "bst    __tmp_reg__,7\n\t"
    "o1bs   %[port]\n\t"
    "delay3\n\t"                        //2
```

`delay1`, `delay2` etc are defined in `asm_macros.h`. Here is a piece of code of `asm_macros.h`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
// delay 1 clock cycle.
".macro delay1\n\t"
    "nop\n"
".endm\n"
```

As you can see, macros are defined. If I try to move `asm_macros.h` to `video_gen.cpp` there is a duplicate macro error (so macros already defined). The only way it can happen is that the Arduino assembler isn't expanding assembler macros. How could I solve this?

Comment: As far as I know, the inline assembler doesn't support macros like the standalone assembler. I don't have an Arduino or any compilation toolchain available for it, but this code won't work on a Gnu compiler targeting x86. I'm not really sure how they ever expected this to work, and they obviously did, since they defined this macro using inline asm in a C header file. And on that note, I'm not even sure how this compiles. GCC barks if you try and annotate a basic asm statement (and it must be basic if it's at file scope) with `__volatile__` because they're all implicitly volatile.

Comment: Does arduino have the same ability gcc has to output the generated assembler (`-S`)?

Comment: I dont know. I make use of Arduino IDE to build the code, but I think it uses GNU compiler and other linker

Comment: Looking at [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37711.0), it talks about how to edit your preferences to 'keep' the temp files, and using the SHIFT key to find out where they are.  Looking at the `ccxegFH3.s` file you mentioned might give you some useful clues.

Comment: It doesn't give any clue. I take a lot of time to get a assembly code, so I could not answer you early. You can find the same code in the assembly file. Example: `.macro delay1
 nop
.endm`

Comment: Hmm.  Well, if the macros are in the file, perhaps they are 'scoped' somehow?  Or they have (somehow) ended up at the bottom of the file and so aren't defined at the point where they are used?

Comment: Inside the header file have you made sure the macros are not being ifdef''ed out somehow?

Comment: In file video_gen.s (assembler file) macros are defined BEFORE their use in the file. This should answer of ifndef question, because the macro definitions are in .s file

Comment: I am getting the same errors but only if a have digitalWrite or digitalRead

Comment: Also the same errors when calculating with floats, when removed it compiles and when added these stupid errors. The file to edit has nothing to do with TVOut lib., weird.